# How do I exactly search a file in my project with atom?

Tags: atom-editor

I know I have a file called 'mwc-fab' in my dependency,
so How can I search this file with the file name?

In vscode, i just type mwc with my node_modules file select and I get the file I want.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using a Windows computer the command is Ctrl+T or Ctrl+P and on Mac Cmd+T or Cmd+P
https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/atom-basics/

Comment: I tried cmd + t and cmd + p, but it shows something but not where the file is.

Comment: If you open the file and then right click anywhere inside the file you you'll see "Open in file manager" or "Open in Finder" on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Atom package named [incremental search](https://atom.io/packages/incremental-search) that you can use to search thru open files. After installing incremental-search you can type command-i and this opens a text box near bottom of screen where you can input your search string. After that you can command-i repeatedly to go to next matching string. Be sure to read the directions for more useful commands.